# php website to android app

Tags: android, ios

I am a novice. I don't understand web programming at all. How do I [turn this](http://cgjobsite.com/tmwsw__craigslist_scraper.php)
into an android app easily?

I have tried https://openshift.redhat.com/app/login?then=%2Fapp%2Fconsole%2Fapplication , but I failed to use it to upload my php file from my tablet.

Comment: you can try [php-js](http://www.php-js.com/) to run the webapp in some javascript environment. Then you can use electron to convert to mobile app. At least thats the [theory](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/languages#compiled-to-javascript). Since you can't compile php.

Answer (score 1):

Loathed be that I am to suggest this, but...

You could make an App with its sole purpose being to hold a WebView.

That WebView could load your scraper.php page.

Comment: I want to convert it to aan android app

Answer (score 0):

Well,
Php is normally the serverside app. In android you got many ways to interact.
If your project includes only small parts of it you can  effectively use webview. Or use the [Http](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.html) class.